# Is it possible to add more Genius Mixes to iTunes 9?

Tags: music, libraries, itunes, playlists

I upgraded to iTunes 9 today and it looks good!

The Genius Mixes feature is nice but I only have 4 genius mixes even though I have 973 songs in my library.  Two of my mixes are even the same genre.

Is there any way to get iTunes to add more Genius Mixes to my 'collection'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

G Mixes is meant to offer you a never ending channel that plays songs that go well together, like a personal radio station.

This means that if most of the music in the library is of just a few genres then the number of mixes will be limited.

To help Genius see what music you have, make sure all the track information is as accurate as possible (Artist, Track Name, Genre), then update Genius (Store menu>Update Genius)
This may help Genius find more compatible music.

And if you want a genius list you can control and edit, then you can generate a song-specific genius playlist, Right click a song then click Start Genius, This playlist displays in “Genius” on the source bar left where you can limit the number of songs in the playlist, Refresh the playlist, delete track from it and even save it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I have 12 with 101.24GB of music. I think 12 is the max. Sometimes after updating, the names change. Here's my current configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just spent about an hour messing with iTunes. This is how it appears to work:

It pulls information from your library in two ways.  It looks at all of the music you have, as well as what is checked.

What I did to "tell" it what to create as a genius mix is this.

- I first unchecked all music.
- Then I updated genius.
- Then I checked groups of genre's that I wanted for my genius mix.

That seemed to work.  It still wasn't perfect, but it was close.

Answer (score 0):

The number of Genius Mixes is determined automatically based on the music you have. For instance, I've got 9 (4 of them are based on rock); my wife only has 4, completely different from what I have, even though she has a subset of the songs I have. I doubt it's possible to influence the number or type of Genius Mixes. It only seems to offer a very spartan experience, with no way of tweaking the results.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

Genius mixes decide for themselves how many different types of music you have, and display that many mixes (unless you have more than 12).

You can add more songs, but that's probably not the solution you're looking for.